# Vector subspaces multiple choice

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $A$ and $B$ be subspaces of a vector space $V$. Which of the following must be subspaces of $V$?

$1. \  A+B = \{a+b: a \in A \ \ \text{and} \ \ b \in B\}$

$2. \  A\cup B$

$3. \  A\cap B$

$4. \  \{x\in V:x\notin A\}$

Multiple choice is possible. Please explain the answer.

Comment: Draw a picture of two lines in the plane to see that 2 and 4 are not subspaces in general. The other two are subspaces, which is quite direct to show once you have recalled the definitons.

Comment: @quid why 2nd isn't a subspace?

Comment: Imagine the two coordinate axis in the plane as $A$ and $B$ now take a (nonzero) point from  each of the two. Is the sum of those two again on one of the coordinate axis? Clearly not. Thus the set is not closed under sum.

Comment: @quid got it, thanks